# Android communication between two applications on two different devices

Tags: android, communication

Is it possible to establish communication between two different apps which are on the two different devices over the internet. I want hit the app which is on one deviceB from the app which is on  deviceA and get data from the app on deviceB to app on deviceA.
If it is possible , How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically only through a server. Mobile devices can not directly connect to each other because [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) prevents establishing inbound connections.

So you will need:

1. User or device identification scheme. How do users find each other? How do the indicate to whom they want to connect to? You need to provide this on your own.
2. Push technology to notify user that someone wants to connect. Use [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/).
3. Your own server through which you'll relay data users want to share/send.

Comment: Regarding 2, now that C2DM is depricated use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If both the devices are in Bluetooth range then the Bluetooth can be used as a communication medium, the [Bluetooth chat application](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) is a good example of this.